# How to get Total Sum of all entries in a Core Data attribute?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, database, xcode, core-data

I've got a Core Data Data Model with an Entity and several Attributes.

One of these Attributes is an Integer 16 (NSDecimalNumber) called

```
numberOfSeconds
```

I want to find the sum of all the entries I have in my data model from this Attribute.

In other words: I'll have many user entries in this Attribute. Lets say the user creates 3 entries with these specifics:

*1) numberOfSeconds = 4*

*2) numberOfSeconds = 2*

*3) numberOfSeconds = 5*

I'm hoping to be able to grab the total sum which should equal *11*.

Appreciate any help in this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSExpressionDescription` to get the sum directly via fetch request (without fetching the managed objects themselves, which can be inefficient if you have many of them).

Remember to set `NSDictionaryResultType` for the fetch request (I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS if I didn't do that).

```
NSExpression *keyExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"numberOfSeconds"];
NSExpression *sumExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[keyExpression]];

NSExpressionDescription *sumDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
sumDescription.name = @"sumOfSeconds";
sumDescription.expression = sumExpression;
[sumDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[sumDescription]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ... //get the context somehow
NSArray* fetchResult = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSNumber *sum = fetchResult.firstObject[sumDescription.name];  //this is your sum
```

Reference: [Apple Core Data guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) - it is something similar to SQL aggregate functions.

Lets assume you previously fetched entities into some collection `entitiesCollection`.

Then it should look like:
`NSNumber *result = [entitiesCollection valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.numberOfSeconds"]`